# JSON does not retain values after Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize a string which is actually an array of object, this is the output of the serialization

```
 [
       {
           \"CallType\":1,\
            "ExecutionStart\":\"2018-07-03T12:25:55.1919951+03:00\",\
            "ExecutionEnd\":\"2018-07-03T12:25:55.3980081+03:00\",\
            "UnitExecutionStart\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\
            "OverallExecution\":205
        }
 ]
```

This is the object to which I want do deserialize

```
[JsonObject]
public class PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX
{
    public PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX()
    {

    }

    public CallType CallType { get; } //=> CallType is an enum
    public DateTime ExecutionStart { get; }
    public DateTime ExecutionEnd { get; }
    public DateTime UnitExecutionStart { get; }
    public long OverallExecution { get; }
}
```

After deserializing

```
var result = value.SelectMany(item =>
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX>>(item));
```

The final object result has default values so it does not retain the value that is stored in the serialized version.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Btw I've tried using

```
var result = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
     .Deserialize<List<PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX>>(value.FirstOrDefault());
```

but the output is the same.

Comment: Is the `value` variable the JSON string? If so, your code is attempting to deserialise a single character to your DTO (remember strings can be treated as char arrays). Try this:

`var dtoList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX>>(value))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX` properties are **readonly**, so `JsonConvert` (and no one, actually) can't assign any value to them, after constructor is invoked. Use this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class PerformanceMetricsItemDtoX
{
    public CallType CallType { get; set; } //=> CallType is an enum
    public DateTime ExecutionStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExecutionEnd { get; set; }
    public DateTime UnitExecutionStart { get; set; }
    public long OverallExecution { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks, completely missed this out. Thanks